# Visualstatemanager in designer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

I have a problem with VisualState in windows phone 8.1, universal app:

I made a simple system to change visual state if screen have a dimension or other... all works well in runtime, but during design, I mean designer, doesn't works.

So I tried VisualStateManager.GoToState(..) but in designer doesn't works, so maybe the solution is to set initial state, but I've tried also with a trigger (beaviour sdk) but ... nothing, so my problem is to have a visual state in designer to easy works with user Interface, in other way set a visual state that works also in designer...

Here's a super simple example

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="small" >
                <Storyboard>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="tmedium">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>    

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="tlarge">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>     

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>


            <VisualState x:Name="medium" />
            <VisualState x:Name="large" />

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


    <TextBlock Name="tsmall"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="small" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock Name="tmedium" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="medium" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock Name="tlarge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,199,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="large" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

this is in code behind:

```
 /// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "small", true);
    }
```

when start a small state is set, but in designer not, so how achieve same result?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by 'the designer doesn't work'? You mean there's no animation transition or there's no effect at all?

Comment: yes "there's no effect at all" in designer, when run on emulator all works, but into designer not.

Comment: Create a repo or show some code?

Comment: I've just update for adding some code to explain better what I mean

Comment: You shouldn't animate visibility, try animating opacity instead.

Comment: @JustinXL what's wrong with animating visibility?  That's what discrete object keyframes are for.

Comment: The visual designer is such a pain ... I would try calling `GoToState` inside the "Loaded" event.  Or, if you want to show "small" in the designer, then maybe you could just make those values the default, and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Of course you can animate the visibility using that, but if your animation only involves visibility, it's the same as setting it directly on the element, there's no smooth transition between visibility animation anyway. I'd also suggest using blend designer, not the vs one.

Comment: thanks for comments but the point is not animation, my problem is how to show during design-time a visual state (small, medium, large) :)